# Binary Search tree , implementing new methods

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an assignment  that want me to make implementation for Binary Search and its methods  and make a new methods for it .. well , i did it but the i didn't know how to make the last 2 tasks :

**4. Once the user is done with insertion/deletion, your program should calculate the balance factor for each node.**

**5. Finally, your program should print the balance factor for each node. If a node is not well-balanced (its balance factor is not 0, 1, or -1), you have to state its imbalanced state (whether it is LL, LR, RR, or RL).**

here's my code :

```
package BST;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> {

  protected TreeNode<E> root;
  protected int size = 0;

  /** Create a default binary tree */
  public BST() {
  }

  /** Create a binary tree from an array of objects */
  public BST(E[] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
      insert(objects[i]);
  }

   /** Returns true if the element is in the tree */
  public boolean search(E e) {
    TreeNode<E> current = root; // Start from the root

    while (current != null) {
      if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
        current = current.left;
      }
      else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
        current = current.right;
      }
      else // element matches current.element
        return true; // Element is found
    }

    return false;
  }

   /** Insert element o into the binary tree
   * Return true if the element is inserted successfully */
  public boolean insert(E e) {
    if (root == null)
      root = createNewNode(e); // Create a new root
    else {
      // Locate the parent node
      TreeNode<E> parent = null;
      TreeNode<E> current = root;
      while (current != null)
        if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
          parent = current;
          current = current.left;
        }
        else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
          parent = current;
          current = current.right;
        }
        else
          return false; // Duplicate node not inserted

      // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
      if (e.compareTo(parent.element) < 0)
        parent.left = createNewNode(e);
      else
        parent.right = createNewNode(e);
    }

    size++;
    return true; // Element inserted
  }

  protected TreeNode<E> createNewNode(E e) {
    return new TreeNode<E>(e);
  }


  public void inorder() {
    inorder(root);
  }


  protected void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    inorder(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
    inorder(root.right);
  }


  public void postorder() {
    postorder(root);
  }


  protected void postorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    postorder(root.left);
    postorder(root.right);
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
  }

   /** Preorder traversal from the root */
  public void preorder() {
    preorder(root);
  }

  /** Preorder traversal from a subtree */
  protected void preorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
    preorder(root.left);
    preorder(root.right);
  }

  /** This inner class is static, because it does not access 
      any instance members defined in its outer class */
  public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    protected E element;
    protected TreeNode<E> left;
    protected TreeNode<E> right;

    public TreeNode(E e) {
      element = e;
    }
  }

   /** Get the number of nodes in the tree */
  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }

  /** Returns the root of the tree */
  public TreeNode<E> getRoot() {
    return root;
  }

  /** Returns a path from the root leading to the specified element */
  public java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> path(E e) {
    java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> list =
      new java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>>();
    TreeNode<E> current = root; // Start from the root

    while (current != null) {
      list.add(current); // Add the node to the list
      if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
        current = current.left;
      }
      else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
        current = current.right;
      }
      else
        break;
    }

    return list; // Return an array of nodes
  }

   /** Delete an element from the binary tree.
   * Return true if the element is deleted successfully
   * Return false if the element is not in the tree */
  public boolean delete(E e) {
    // Locate the node to be deleted and also locate its parent node
    TreeNode<E> parent = null;
    TreeNode<E> current = root;
    while (current != null) {
      if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
        parent = current;
        current = current.left;
      }
      else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
        parent = current;
        current = current.right;
      }
      else
        break; // Element is in the tree pointed at by current
    }

    if (current == null)
      return false; // Element is not in the tree

    // Case 1: current has no left children
    if (current.left == null) {
      // Connect the parent with the right child of the current node
      if (parent == null) {
        root = current.right;
      }
      else {
        if (e.compareTo(parent.element) < 0)
          parent.left = current.right;
        else
          parent.right = current.right;
      }
    }
    else {
      // Case 2: The current node has a left child
      // Locate the rightmost node in the left subtree of
      // the current node and also its parent
      TreeNode<E> parentOfRightMost = current;
      TreeNode<E> rightMost = current.left;

      while (rightMost.right != null) {
        parentOfRightMost = rightMost;
        rightMost = rightMost.right; // Keep going to the right
      }

      // Replace the element in current by the element in rightMost
      current.element = rightMost.element;

      // Eliminate rightmost node
      if (parentOfRightMost.right == rightMost)
        parentOfRightMost.right = rightMost.left;
      else
        // Special case: parentOfRightMost == current
        parentOfRightMost.left = rightMost.left;     
    }

    size--;
    return true; // Element inserted
  }


  public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new InorderIterator();
  }

  // Inner class InorderIterator
  private class InorderIterator implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
    // Store the elements in a list
    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list =
      new java.util.ArrayList<E>();
    private int current = 0; // Point to the current element in list

    public InorderIterator() {
      inorder(); // Traverse binary tree and store elements in list
    }


    private void inorder() {
      inorder(root);
    }


    private void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
      if (root == null)return;
      inorder(root.left);
      list.add(root.element);
      inorder(root.right);
    }

     /** More elements for traversing? */
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (current < list.size())
        return true;

      return false;
    }


    public E next() {
      return list.get(current++);
    }


    public void remove() {
      delete(list.get(current)); // Delete the current element
      list.clear(); // Clear the list
      inorder(); // Rebuild the list
    }
  }


  public void clear() {
    root = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      BST<Integer> a = new BST<>();
     int num = 0;
      System.out.println("How many nummbers do you want to insert ? ");
      num = in.nextInt();
      for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
         a.insert(in.nextInt());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that you'll have to have an actual question before anyone can answer it. Now you've just stated what you need to do. Also without specific problem and specific code this goes into *too broad* category which will get it closed.

Comment: [Read up on your subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Balance_factor).  Once you know what it is, you should be able to calculate it using a recursive method.